# w3school asp.net syntax appears to not be asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I was looking at [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_database.asp) and the `@{` look neat. I modified the example and made a new asp.net project. My code is below. My results were not expected. This showed up on my browser

```
@foreach(var row in new int[1,4,3]) { @row }
```

Now i'm assuming that the code on the page is asp.net and that i am doing something wrong.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
@foreach(var row in new int[1,4,3])
{
<tr> 
<td>@row</td> 
</tr> 
}
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is running on ASP.NET MVC and is a Razor view, the actual file is ListProducts.cshtml which is a combiniation of c# and html

Comment: [W3Schools tutorials are often not very accurate and helpful](http://www.w3fools.com)

Comment: Leave it to W3Schools to mix Razor with an XHTML doctype and webforms...legal, but come on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MVC3, search about it with Razor View Engine.

Answer (score 3):

This is Razor syntax, very easy and flexible used in asp.net mvc.

[Visit the link](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax)

Comment: I have MSVS2012 installed. I don't seem to find MVC or Razor. How do I get to it and do I need to install it separately?

Comment: There can be default support for any web application. You should check syntax selection while starting project.

Answer (score 0):

In MSVS2012, MVC is included with ultimate and express edition.
else you can take help from here
[asp.net MVC4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4)